# Append to the top in a log file

Tags: shell-script, scripting

I have a crontab script which monitor a DR process between 2 machines and this script generate a log file. What i have been asked to do is basically append the new log generated on the top of the previous (as log i use the same file name) and not on the bottom.

I've seen already few options, but all my tentative failed.

I tried with

```
cat $LOGFILE >> $TEMPLOG
rm $LOGFILE
mv -i $TEMPLOG $LOGFILE
```

and also with

```
cat - $LOGFILE > $TEMPLOG && mv $TEMPLOG $LOGFILE
```

the variable $LOGFILE is where the script append every single statement of the process.

Thanks :)

Basically want I'd like to to do is generate the right log with on top the last run before it is sent by mail.

```
DATE=`date "+%d%m%y_%H%M"`
PRIMARY_HOSTNAME=`hostname`
LOGFILE=/dba/logs/monitor_sync_FM2.log
TEMPLOG=/dba/logs/monitor_sync_LOG.log
SERVER=`hostname`
SITE=mycompany
EMAILTO="email@company.com"
DBOPS="oracle@${SERVER}.${SITE}"

export PRIMARY_HOSTNAME LOGFILE TEMPLOG SERVER SITE EMAILTO DBOPS DATE
echo "\n\n### monitor DR sync  started @ `date` ###" >> $LOGFILE
echo "Running SQL command to verify latest SCN.." >> $LOGFILE
echo "The current SCN of the Primary DB server is: $PRIMARY_CURRENT_SCN" >> $LOGFILE

echo "Connecting now to the secondary standby database server..." >> $LOGFILE
SECONDARY_CURRENT_SCN=`ssh oracle@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx /home/oracle/script_sync2.sh` >> $LOGFILE
export SECONDARY_CURRENT_SCN
echo "Secondary SCN output returned as: $SECONDARY_CURRENT_SCN" >> $LOGFILE
grep ORA- /dba/scripts/output.txt
if [ $? = 0 ]; then
echo "Remote ssh command to Secondary server failed..Exiting" >> $LOGFILE
echo "### monitor DR sync failed @ `date` ###" >> $LOGFILE
echo "PROBLEM" >> $LOGFILE

mailx -r ${DBOPS} -s "PROBLEM" ${EMAILTO} < $LOGFILE
exit
else
echo "The current SCN of the Secondary DB server is: $SECONDARY_CURRENT_SCN" >> $LOGFILE
DIFF=`expr $PRIMARY_CURRENT_SCN - $SECONDARY_CURRENT_SCN` ; export DIFF
if [ $PRIMARY_CURRENT_SCN -ne $SECONDARY_CURRENT_SCN ]; then
        echo "The difference is $DIFF" >> $LOGFILE
        if [ `echo $DIFF` -gt 3 ]; then
                echo "Log Gap: $DIFF" >> $LOGFILE
                                echo "PROBLEM" >> $LOGFILE
                                echo "### script finished @ `date` ###\n\n" >> $LOGFILE
                mailx -r ${DBOPS} -s "PROBLEM" ${EMAILTO}  < ${LOGFILE}
        else
                                echo "SUCCESS" >> $LOGFILE
                mailx -r ${DBOPS} -s "SUCCESS" ${EMAILTO}  < ${LOGFILE}
                echo "Log Gap: $DIFF" >> $LOGFILE
        fi
else
echo "Log Gap: $DIFF" >> $LOGFILE
echo "SUCCESS" >> $LOGFILE
mailx -r ${DBOPS} -s "SUCCESS" ${EMAILTO}  < ${LOGFILE}
fi
fi
```

Comment: Why does it needed to be added to the beginning of the file?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Because the will be sent to a machine with a monitoring agent which check from the top of the file, so i'd like to have the last run/checking on the top

Comment: @MarkPlotnick sorry, i don't get your comment

Comment: Does each line of the logfile have a timestamp? If so, and you want newer portions of the logfile added at the top, does that mean that the timestamps will not all be in order?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Yes, there is a time stamp on the top of the portion of log generate every run. And i don't mind that won't be in order, it won't be a problem.

Comment: Generate the log as ordinary people do, but look at it in reverse with `tac`.

Comment: @Kusalananda because i'm not an ordinary person and also is not what i need, is not me that need to read the log, but a monitoring agent that read just from the top of the file, as i said above here

Answer (score 1):

If you want to "append" (insert) the current run's logs to the beginning of the existing log file, then follow through with your apparent attempt at using a TEMPLOG file.  Write all of the script's output/data to that $TEMPLOG file, then do:

```
ed -s $LOGFILE <<< "0r $TEMPLOG"$'\n'wq
```

To `r`ead $TEMPLOG into $LOGFILE after line zero.

As an example:

```
$ cat logfile
previous
entries
here
$ cat templog
New
Entry goes
Here
$ ed -s "$LOGFILE" <<< "0r $TEMPLOG"$'\n'wq
$ cat logfile
New
Entry goes
Here
previous
entries
here
```

If your shell does not support here-strings, print the instructions to ed's stdin instead:

```
printf "0r $TEMPLOG\nwq\n" | ed -s logfile
```

If you only need the contents of the *email* to be changed, and not the $LOGFILE itself, just prepend it in the pipe to mail:

```
cat "$TEMPLOG" "$LOGFILE" | mailx -r ${DBOPS} -s "SUCCESS" ${EMAILTO}
```

Comment: Hi Jeff, i tried your suggestion with ed but it doesn't work:

./monitor_sync_1_FMn2.sh[41]: syntax error at line 45 : `<' unexpected

Should i use a specific shell for it?

Comment: Yes; I think bash, zsh, and ksh support it (it’s a here-string as distinguished from a here-document)

Comment: Hi Jeff, i just tried to run that command out of the script with 2 random files in KSH but still no joy:

scripts $ ed -s FM2.test <<< "0r IG.test"$'\n'wq
ksh: syntax error: `<' unexpected

Comment: Are you working with ksh v88 maybe?

Comment: @FaMontyN2, I've added a non-here-string option to the answer; see if that works any better.

Answer (score 1):

Since your script appends to `$LOGFILE`, I think what you want is

```
mv $LOGFILE $TEMPLOG
```

at the beginning and

```
cat $TEMPLOG >>$LOGFILE
```

just before mailing.